# CSS targeted theming

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was a way in CSS to package styles under a specific div to be different. Here is an example of what I would like to accomplish:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="enableTheme">
     <p>some themed html</p>
  </div>
  <div id="disableTheme">
     <p>some none-themed html</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css would do something like this:

```
#enableTheme{
    p{
       css styles
    }
    label{
       different styles
    }
    div{
       even more different styles
    }
    ...
 }
```

where everything under the div that has the id "enableTheme" would be themed the way I want it to be.

Thank you in advance for the help

*edit*: sorry guys I wasnt very clear in my question. I know about the

```
#enableTheme p{ 
   //Styles
}
```

but my problem is I have a hude css file that I dont want to have to add the "#enableTheme" one by one to each element, thats why I was wondering if there was a way to do it globally for a pack of styles that I had premade.

Comment: I think your easiest be would be to add/remove classes to a parent element. so in css `#enableTheme p {}` would apply where `p{}` wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much there.  Try

```
#enableTheme p {
  /* styles */
}

#enableTheme label {
  /* and on and on */
}
```

Incidentally, if you used [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/), what you'd written would output exactly the CSS you want for this situation.

Edit: ...but I'd recommend learning more about CSS before getting into Less/Sass/SCSS

Answer (score 0):

In regular CSS no, you can't do that. But you could do something like:

```css
#enableTheme p{
       css styles
}
#enableTheme label{
       different styles
}
#enableTheme div{
       even more different styles
}
```

Note that there are options, like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), that allow you to do what you proposed.

Comment: @Jared - this is regular CSS. I was saying to the OP that he can't do what he outlined using regular CSS (the nesting).

Comment: gotcha.  Wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious there.

Answer (score 0):

Use that syntax:

```
#enableTheme p{
   css styles
}
#enableTheme label{
   different styles
}
#enableTheme div{
   even more different styles
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

(this is probably a duplicate, but anyway)

Yes, this is the [Descendant Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors). Just do this:

```
#enableTheme p
{
   css styles
}

#enableTheme label
{
   different styles
}

#enableTheme div
{
   even more different styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#enableTheme p {

}

#enableTheme label {

}

#enableTheme div {

}
```

or, if they're direct descendants, you may use

```
#enableTheme > p {

}

#enableTheme > label {

}

#enableTheme > div {

}
```